# How to print out all the title on a page with a with a web crawler?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to program an app, which shows the time table of the buses which go to the town. Could you please help me?

This is what I have written yet, but it is not working (I only want the titles, or "times" of the buses on the page);

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def RuterBuss(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://ruter.no/reiseplanlegger/Mellom/Fra/(2190085)
            %C3%98ster%C3%A5s%20senter%20(B%C3%A6rum)/til/(3010200)Majorstuen
            %20%5bT-bane%5d%20(Oslo)/etter/#st:0,sp:0,bp:0' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('span', {'class':'route-list__title ng-binding'}):
            title = link.string
            print(title)
        page += 1

RuterBuss(1)
```

The outcome is:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

As I said, I want the times on when the buses go. Can you see what I have forgotten or done wrong

Comment: the bus times are rendered via Angular so you will likely need a JavaScript parser to obtain the times

Answer (score 0):

The reason because your output is

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

is basically because your code doesn't reach any print statement.

More in details, this means that the `soup` variable is an empty list for the first (and the only one) iteraction of the while loop.

Anyway I have looked the page that you use in your script and I think that is not possible reach information as you are doing because the page is rendered via AngularJS. In fact, I tried to change your for loop in this way:

```
for link in soup.findAll('strong'):
```

because I have analyzed the source and the wanted information are available in `<strong>` element, but the results are the following:

```
{{travel.routeName}}
{{travel.formattedDepartureTime}} – {{travel.formattedArrivalTime}}
{{deviation.heading}}
{{deviation.heading}}
{{remark.heading}}
{{deviation.heading}}
```

Another idea that I had, was search in the developer tools (console) of the browser if there is any XHR or JS to get the requested information, maybe via json, but i didn't find anything.